# Why does 'touch' ing makefile along with all source file does not rebuild anything? How can I solve this?

Tags: build, makefile, touch

I have some source files like `file1`, `file2` and `file3` and a `Makefile`:

```
tar: file1 file2 file3
    @echo hello
```

Now when I `touch file1`, it rebuilds `file1` and `tar`.

But when I `touch` all source files and `Makefile`, it does not rebuild anything. It should rebuild all source files. Why so?

Simple solution is I `touch` all file but `Makefile`, but it becomes difficult when I have say 20 source files. What is the solution?

Comment: When you do the touch, is it possible the tar file is also being touched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way make works is to compare the timestamp on the target and the source(s). The general format of the rule is:

```
target: source(s)
    action(s)
```

In this case, when you run `make`, it will look at the target's timestamp (`tar`) and ask whether that timstamp is older than the timestamp of any source (`file`, `file2`, `file3`). If the target is older than any of the sources, then it is considered out of date, which triggers the rule's action(s) to run.

The problem is that this rule doesn't do anything except to echo output. After it runs, `tar` still has the same timestamp it had before. The next time you run `make`, it will do exactly the same thing, because the starting condition (the timestamps) did not change.

You can make this work as expected by having the rule touch the tar file as one of its actions.

```make
tar: file1 file2 file3
    @touch tar
    @echo hello
```

Now it should behave as expected.

```
$ make
make: `tar' is up to date.
$ touch file3    
$ make
hello
$ make
make: `tar' is up to date.
```

Of course, in a typical Makefile, your rule would do more than `echo`. If it is building something, normally the target of the rule (in this case `tar`) is modified as a result of the build action, so explicitly using `touch` is not usually required.

Comment: I think you missed a point that I am running touch command on all files which updates timestamp of all the files. This means all source file timestamps are updated and tar should rebuild. But here, after running touch command, it returns " 'tar' is up to date "

Comment: @Harsh By "all files" here do you mean all files *including* `tar`? If you did `touch tar file1 file2 file3` or `touch *` and ran make, it would say it was already up to date, because tar is not older than any of the source files.

Comment: yes, I did `touch *`. I got your point now that timestamp of tar is compared with sourcefiles' timestamp. Earlier I misunderstood that sourcefiles' time stamp are compared with their previous timestamps stored somewhere. I got your point now. Thanks.

Comment: How do I touch all files but `tar`?

Comment: @Harsh That depends on your filenames, the easiest way is with wildcards like `touch file*` ... but outside of the example filenames in your post I don't know what your files are called, it's hard to say. The `touch` utility doesn't have an "all except this one" capability in it as far as I know.

Comment: @Harsh Normally you don't do that, though - the idea behind `make` is that as you update source files, `make` will notice and rebuild what needs to be rebuilt, but the updated timestamps usually come from editing a file, copying a new version of it in, etc, not from specific `touch` commands. But `touch` has the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Dan. You are really helpful... :)